# Object cannot be selected and only appears in Object mode?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I have this box in my model, and I cannot select it at all, even with the b key, and it only appears in Object mode, and cannot be seen in Edit mode. How do you delete it?

Comment: Did you make the box, or did it appear out of nowhere? Also, can you select it in the outliner?

Answer (score 1):

I think you accidentally hid it (pressed <kbd>H</kbd> key).
go to edit mode and unhide it by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>.